# How do I code a formula to apply to an entire column in Google sheets, even when you insert a new row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a basic cash flow Google Sheet that I use to track my personal finances, cash in and out of my checking account.

Here's basically what it looks like:

```
   Column A    Column B     Column C
```

Row 1  | Water bill  |  -50.00  |    400.00

Row 2 | Credit card | -300.00   |  100.00   >> the formula here is =sum(C1,B2)

Row 3 |  Paycheck    |   2000.00  |  2100.00  >> the formula here is =sum(C2,B3)

I project this out a full year. Anytime I want to add a row, I have to manually apply the formula in column C, and then I also have to fix the formula in the row just below it, which then fixes the problem for the rest of the sheet.

In Google Sheets, Is there a way for me to hard-code a formula for Column C that would allow me to insert a new row and always have it math perfectly without having to manually add the formula, and fix the formula in the row below it?

Let me know if there would be an easier way to do this by making fundamental changes to how it's setup - this is just how I've done it for so long, and I'm looking for a way to automate this going forward.

I've heard array formula might be helpful, but I'm not sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many kinds of ArrayFormulas and LAMBDA functions. I suggest you look into them for different cases and uses. There is one kind in particular that would serve to your purposes:

```
=SCAN(0,B2:B,LAMBDA(a,v,a+v))
```

If you put this in C2 you'll have a cumulative sum row by row. Try it and let me know!

If you want to hide the results if column B is empty you can use another ARRAYFORMULA to check if B is empty it returns empty, either way returns the SCAN result:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="","",SCAN(0,B2:B,LAMBDA(a,v,a+v))))
```

Comment: Thank you Martin - can I ask you for a litle more help on how to setup a,v and a+v? I'm not sure what that refers to. Thank you.

Comment: `a` is the name I assigned to the initial value and accumulator. In this case I started with 0 (the first argument in Scan) and then `a` will become the new value for the next row (that's why it's the "accumulator"). `v` is the name I assigned to each value from B colum that is "being scanned". Basically SCAN repeats the same process row by row, "saving" the prior value inside the accumulator and applying the formula with the new value. Because of the accumulator, you don't need to add C1+B2,C2+B3 and so on. The result is saved inside it

Comment: Actually the last part of the scan is the actual operation. In the first part you're setting the variables and their names. They could be named as you desire, for example: `=SCAN(0,B2:B,LAMBDA(subtotal,newvalue, subtotal+newvalue))`

Comment: YES, ok wow I think it works!!! Martin you have saved me a lifetime of frustration!!! THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert a new row in between then it's quite tedious as it will mess up the formulas below it, but if you just keep appending a new entry on the bottom row, then the formula will smartly mimic the behavior above it. Then you can simply do this:

1. [Select the current last row, then click the small dot at the end and drag it down to as much as you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkN1O.png)
2. OR, Ctrl+C (Copy) the last row, then select as much empty rows beneath it as you want, then Ctrl+V (Paste)